# Is there any Looking for Group tool?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is there any Looking for Group tool in Guild Wars 2? I'm trying to do a dungeon, but I can't find a party to complete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no tool in-game with a Looking for Group feature.

As a turnout, there's a website called [gw2lfg.com](http://gw2lfg.com/) which several players use to join or search parties. You can join parties from [players from other worlds](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/World#Playing_together).

Alternatively, you may also change your "Status" to "Looking For Group" (Which applies a Blue Magnifier to the right of your character name). This is great for Dungeon Doors, where you may "say" without typing that you are open for a party invite.

As soon as you join a party, your status is switched back to the previous one.

Comment: Stand in Lions Arch and use `/m LFG for <dungeon>` and you'll get a group inside 5 minutes. Probably longer now as everyone seems to be doing fractals :/

Comment: @DavidYell that works if you're doing something popular like AC exp..

Comment: Also see if you can join a large guild; even if you only represent it for specific events (dungeons, WvW, etc), it's a handy resource for party members.  You can even gauge interest while out on the field without having to return to LA first.